# How to read only the first line of a file

Tags: perl, file, readline

I've been googling for a while, but I cannot find a function the read just first line of a file.

I need to read first line of a text file and extract the date from it.

new to perl.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
open my $file, '<', "filename.txt"; 
my $firstLine = <$file>; 
close $file;
```

Answer (score 7):

```
open THEFILE, "<filename.txt";
$first_line = <THEFILE>;
close THEFILE;
```

Comment: You should use lexical filehandles and three argument `open`.

Answer (score 3):

```
open( my $file, "x.txt");
$line = <$file>;
```

Answer (score 1):

... a modern and popular alternative:

```
use Path::Tiny;
(my $firstline) = path('filename.txt')->lines( { count => 1 } );
```

For more info https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny#lines-lines_raw-lines_utf8

**Note:** since `->lines` is returning a list, calling it without the brackets around `$firstline` it will be assigned the number of lines which have been read from `filename.txt`: 1 (or 0 if it's empty).

Comment: You might want to `chomp $firstline;` or the value could have a newline at the end and that might not be something you want.