# Getting first line of file as argument of script in Perl

Tags: perl, file, line

So, I need to get out the first line of file, and use its information for some purpose later.
Also, I need to get the remaining lines from that same file and use information from first line to do something. I tried by the textbook this:

```
while (defined ($lines = <>))
    {
      #do something
    }
```

How to extract first line from this in Perl?.. I am new in programming, any advice would help.

Comment: On reading the first line of a file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028250/how-to-read-only-the-first-line-of-a-file

Answer (score 8):

Just read the first line before the loop starts:

```
my $first_line = <>;
while (my $line = <>) {
    # do whatever you like with $first_line and $line
}
```

If you want all the remaining lines in an array, no loop is needed at all:

```
my ($first_line, @lines) = <>;
```

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that the first line also will be read by the while loop... I dont need to read it again..

Comment: @Gyrfalcon: It will not, unless you open the file again or `seek` to the beginning.